# How to solve: $\cos^2x + \sin x = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\cos^2x + \sin x = 1$

How to solve for $x$?

Comment: Do you know a nice trigonometric identity involving $\cos^2 x$?

Comment: $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$.  Use this to obtain a quadratic equation in the variable $\sin x$.

Comment: $\cos^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x$, thus $\cos^2 x + \sin x = 1 \implies 1 - \sin^2 x + \sin x = 1 \implies \sin^2 x - \sin x = 0$ either $x=k2\pi$ or (change variables) $z^2 - z = 0 \implies z - 1 = 0$ thus $\sin x = 1 \implies x=..$

Comment: Ah so you guys are suggesting I use $\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$

Comment: Thanks guys! You saved me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\color{red}{\cos^2x}+\sin x&=\color{blue}{1}\\
\color{red}{1-\sin^2x}+\sin x-\color{blue}{1}&=0\\
\sin x-\sin^2x&=0\\
\sin x(1-\sin x)&=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Define $z:=\sin x$.

Then $z=1-\cos^2 x=z^2$.

The second equation is based on: $$\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$$
wich is true for any $x$.

Having solved $z$ start solving $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos^2x+\sin x=1=\cos^2x+\sin^2x\quad=>\quad\sin x=\sin^2x\quad=>\quad\sin x\in\{0,1\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos^2 x  = 1- \sin^2 x $

plug it in and you get: $ 1- \sin^2 x +\sin x =1$ , which is $\sin x(1-\sin x) = 0$

solve for $ \sin x = 0$ and  $\sin x = 1$ and you get general solutions...put $k\in Z$ for desired solutions in specific range.